# How do I use iOS auto resizing cells without specifying estimated row height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios8, uikit

I want to leverage Auto Layout taking care of my cell heights automatically in iOS 8, but I hate how finicky estimated row heights make scrolling (jumpy, scroll position unpredictable, etc.).

Is there a way to not use estimation so that the table view precalculates all row heights like it did pre iOS 7 (not too many cells so not a performance issue) but uses iOS 8's auto calculating for heights?

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

There is no way to use dynamic sizing without using this property. `estimatedRowHeight` tells the system to use a dynamic size, assuming you used Auto layout in you cell.

Watch WWDC 2014 Video 226.

//

Very simple - create your prototype cell in the Storyboard, add constraints to the superview top/bottom (aka the cell content view), meaning your subviews have top/bottom constraints that will "push" the cell size when necessary.

Make the that both the TableView and the Cell height are set to Default. If that's problem (auto layout required more height than the default 44 pts) then make sure to do it in code:
`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
Don't forget to set the `estimatedRowHeight` to tell the system you want dynamic sizing enabled.

Comment: I asked without specifying estimatedRowHeight. That's your last line.

Comment: Yes it is. You can do it without but this will make the height unstable. You have to provide at least the default value (44) to allow the table to work well with auto layout.

Comment: +1, if the answer is not clear for you (like me) here's the same thing in my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33051556/1028256

Answer (score 1):

Auto-sizing requires that you provide estimated row heights, but you can precalculate row heights using auto layout.

To do that you'll need a "dummy" cell filled with data for the cell which size you're trying to calculate. And then you can use auto-layout to do the work for you:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static YourCell *dummy = nil;
    static NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCell" bundle:nil];
        dummy = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
        widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintWithItem:dummy.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:
NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:320.0]; 
        widthConstraint.priority = 750; //Good idea to lower priority of this constraint so it doesn't interfere with whatever table view sets internally
        [dummy addConstraint:widthConstraint];
    });

    //account for current table view width
    widthConstraint.constant = tableView.bounds.width; 

    //...
    //Configure dummy cell here
    //...

    CGSize size = [dummy systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height;
}
```

Comment: I'm finding it doesn't seem to work without setting an Explicit Width on the label that is the decider in the cell's size. Is it possible to not do this, as it complicates dimensions when the device is rotated? And for setting the width on the cell, do you mean the subviews in the cell? And if so, is positioning it away from all the sides (setting leading, trailing, top and bottom spacing) sufficient? Any way you could show this in a sample project?

Comment: Pushed a sample to github https://github.com/alexchugunov/Examples/tree/master/TableViewAutoLayoutExample. The important part is to add a width constraint on the contentView, because contentView doesn't have it unless the cell was created by the table view. Also, disregard my previous suggestion to call systemLayoutSizeFittingSize on the contentView. You should do it on the cell itself as it will account for separators and other views inside the cell. Edited my answer as well.

Comment: How is the cell *not* created by the table view?

Comment: In my example above I'm creating a cell using UINib class (the Xib file has a single UITableViewCell view in it). Note, that I only use this cell to calculate the size. Table view will take care of creating all cells that will actually be displayed.

Comment: Hello @DougSmith did you solve this. I am also facing a similar issue like this, my SO question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101840/uitableview-bounces-with-estimatedrowheight

Answer (score 1):

you can use either

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or

```
_activityTable.estimatedRowHeight = [CompanyEventCell cellHeight];
```