# UITableView bounces with estimatedRowHeight

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using autoLayout for my customCell in xib, because I want to have variable height for rows based on the text.

Now in my VC.m

I am using these lines of code

```
- (void)viewdidLoad
{
    m_tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];       
    m_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 97.0;
   m_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

here is my cellForRow function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *tableCell = (NotesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (tableCell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        tableCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }    
    // Configure the cell...


     //This code is used to make the separator full width. Also the tableview separator insets should be set to zero

    tableCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    tableCell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;

    return tableCell;
}
```

So now whenever I update a row I call these lines of code

```
[m_tableView beginUpdates];
    [m_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:m_indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [m_tableView endUpdates];
```

When I do this, by Tableview just bounces. I dont know what is going wrong

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you reload your cell the table view is asking for the heights of all the cells again.  Any cells that are offscreen above your scroll position will be asked for their estimated row heights and if they are different from their current height it will cause the cells to change height and you will see the table bounce like that.

Once your cells have their heights calculated you should cache that value somewhere and then implement `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return the cells actual height if they have one instead of your estimated height.

Comment: How to cache row height, because I am not using heightforRowAtIndexPath. Also I am not calculating any row height. I am depending on estimated row height

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` rather than the version you are using.

The one you are using will have no size class due to the fact the cell returned has no parent. Its an issue which appears from xcode 6 onwards due to the size class changes.

Try changing to this version which returns a cell which is part of the table and thus inherits the traitCollection of the superviews and helps the layout to work properly.

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion, but no luck. tableview still bounces

Comment: If you just call `[m_tableView reloadData]` rather than `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` as a test does it bounce?

Comment: Also where are you calling the reload from?

Comment: yes, it works if I use [m_tableView reloadData]. But this bouncing issue is also on deleteRowsAtIndexPath and there if i just call [m_tableView reloadData] then I will not get animation

Comment: I didnt get your second question

Comment: Where in the code do you call the reload rows, delete rows methods.  You have to watch where you call them from. Bouncing sounds like its has got confused which sounds like a issue with one set of operations interfering with another.

Comment: When I delete row I call deleteRowsAtIndexPath, and I have checked [reloadData] is not interfering with it. I dont want to lose animation effect on  when deleting rows

Comment: You might need to show more code. Documentation also warns about calling setEditing:animated: from withing commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath in case you are calling that?

Comment: No, I am not using that function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73233/discussion-between-ranjit-and-rory-mckinnel).