# size class for table row height in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I develop an iOS app with Swift and storyboard. I placed a table and I need to change table cell height depending on screen class, but I can't find such option in table options. I see that cell height is defined by Table View / Row height option, but it doesn't support class sizes.

This problem happens because I set fonts of labels in the cell prototype using size classes, so for bigger screens fonts are bigger, but row height can't be  changed per size class. I need a higher row for bigger fonts, obviously. What approach should I use to achieve it?

Obj-C code will do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question - in iOS 8 it's possible to enable auto layout for cells using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for table's row height:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

`estimatedRowHeight` needs to be set too.

Links:

http://natashatherobot.com/ios-8-self-sizing-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-type/

http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918600/1028256

Answer (score 0):

Set it by code using the the UITableView Delegate.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        //check the conditions and return the row height.

            return 71.0;
}
```

You can find the similar delegate in Swift also.

Comment: I may accept this answer if there's no way to do it in storyboard. Also, how to check in code which screen size class is currently used?